networkd-dispatcher multiple error messages in log
I am trying to get Strongswan working (Currently using compiled version of strongswan) but I am getting repeated messages from networkd-dispatcher that I think may be part of why it's not working.
2024-09-29T23:04:13.076212-04:00 huginn systemd[1]: networkd-dispatcher.service: Got notification message from PID 845217, but reception only permitted for main PID 987
2024-09-29T23:04:13.078277-04:00 huginn networkd-dispatcher[987]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 20 seen even after reload
2024-09-29T23:04:13.078681-04:00 huginn networkd-dispatcher[987]: WARNING:Unknown index 20 seen, reloading interface list
2024-09-29T23:04:13.089286-04:00 huginn systemd[1]: networkd-dispatcher.service: Got notification message from PID 845218, but reception only permitted for main PID 987
2024-09-29T23:04:13.091384-04:00 huginn networkd-dispatcher[987]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 20 seen even after reload

I tried the other fix that was mentioned in a couple other places, but it was already installed, so that isn't the issue:
 sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-45-generic is already the newest version (6.8.0-45.45).
linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-45-generic set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

ps -ef | grep 987
root         987       1  0 Sep16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
root      845349  844412  0 23:07 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 987

This is on Ubuntu Server 24.04.1 LTS.
How can I resolve this?
